# Does מין mean Christian, and if so what are the implications?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, christianity, heresy

From what I have read there seems to be [ample evidence](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10846-min) that the term מין, as used in several places [in the talmud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkat_HaMinim), refers to Christians. I would like to know if there are any authorities who cite this definition l'halacha and what the implications might be. For example if a person has a relative who converts to Christianity (חס ושלום) upon the death of that relative must that person not  mourn, but assume festive garments and rejoice (Yoreh De'ah, 345)?

Please note I realize that the term מין can and perhaps does apply to other categories of people as well.

Comment: Are you asking about the usage of the term across all halachik literature? The answer then is definitely no. Perhaps try limiting to its usage in a particular work (eg the Jerusalem Talmud) or a time period (eg. Gaonic Babylonia)

Comment: @DoubleAA better? I am asking about its use in the talmud and what practical halachic impact that may have today

Comment: In the sefer bmichetzos Rabbeinu min stands for mtalmidai yeshu notri

Comment: christianity would be heresy either way for a Jew so what *nafka mina* is there? (though your example may often be dealt with differently nowadays.)

Comment: @sam in the uncensored version of Rashi to Megillah 17b he says basically the same thing